# Call NodeJS Function in AngularJS

Tags: mysql, angularjs, json, node.js, excel

```
app.get("/myDBfunction",getCommunicationDetails);    
function myDBfunction(req,res){
     var queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
         console.log("req.method ",req.method);

    var resultset={};
        resultset.result=[];


     var queryString = `select * from table..`
     connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
                    if (!err){
                var response = [];
                response.push({'result' : 'success'});
                if (result.length != 0) {
                    response.push({'data' : result});
                } else {
                    response.push({'msg' : 'No Result Found'});
                }

                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
            } else {
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
    })
        };
```

I have created Nodejs function for connection to mysql and able to display in json format.
Now i want to call this function in angular js and convert my json to excel and download the report.
I am new in Angular pls help me with full steps.
Thanks in Advance.

**Edit 1:**
Firstpro.html file

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>

    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <script src="/app.js"></script>
    <h1>Export to Excel</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#tableToExport')">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
 Export to Excel
    </button>
    <div id="tableToExport">
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-header">
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Process Type</th>
            <th>Cedent</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="data in details">
            <td>{{data.team}}</td>
            <td>{{data.type}}</td>
            <td>{{data.cedent}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

myCtrl.js file

```
myApp.controller('myController',funtion($scope,$http){
   $http.get("/Details").then(function(response){ 
       $scope.details = response.data; //You get your data here from nodejs API, and iterate details in your View
     });
});
```

app.js File

```
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.factory('Excel',function($window){
        var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('myCtrl',function(Excel,$timeout,$scope,$http){
      //get data from Node api; For example i will using $timeout just to simulate api call; Also i am assuming your JSON would be like below that i have assigned

      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.details = [
           { 
             team:'v1',
             type:'v2',
             cedent:'v3'
           },
           { 
             team:'v1',
             type:'v2',
             cedent:'v3'
           },
           { 
             team:'v1',
             type:'v2',
             cedent:'v3'
           }
        ]
      },1000)

      //below is how you would do your HTTP call tp node js server. I have commented this codefor now just to simulate the dummy data above in $timeout.
      /*$http.get("/myDBfunction").then(function(response){ 
       $scope.details = response.data; //You get your data here from nodejs API, and iterate details in your View
      });*/


      $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
            var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
            $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
        }
    });
```

Now Simply i have run myHTML file output is like;
but it should take from MYsql table.
Export to Excel

```
Export to Excel
Team    Process Type    Cedent
{{data.team}}   {{data.type}}   {{data.cedent}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2**

to fetch data from SQL use below code instead of `$timeout`

```
$http.get("/myDBfunction").then(function(response){ 
      console.log(response.data)
      $scope.details = response.data; // here you will get data
 },function(res){
      console.log("Error",res) //error occured
 });
```

**EDIT**
[image: See this HTML screenshot]

you can call nodejs api like below in your controller and can display that JSON resulted in View in tabular format using 'ng-repeat'

In your controller  :

```
myApp.controller('myController',funtion($scope,$http){
   $http.get("/myDBfunction").then(function(response){ 
       $scope.details = response.data; //You get your data here from nodejs API, and iterate details in your View
     });
});
```

and In view repeat over that data

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="data in details track by $index" > // here I made changes
      <td> {{data.prop1}} //iterate over data here</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

then follow below coded to export in excel

```js
// This will be your app.js file
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.factory('Excel',function($window){
        var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl',function(Excel,$timeout,$scope,$http){
      //get data from Node api; For example i will using $timeout just to simulate api call; Also i am assuming your JSON would be like below that i have assigned
      
      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.details = [
           { 
             team:'v1',
             type:'v2',
             cedent:'v3'
           },
           { 
             team:'v1',
             type:'v2',
             cedent:'v3'
           },
           { 
             team:'v1',
             type:'v2',
             cedent:'v3'
           }
        ]
      },1000)
      
      //below is how you would do your HTTP call tp node js server. I have commented this codefor now just to simulate the dummy data above in $timeout.
      /*$http.get("/myDBfunction").then(function(response){ 
       $scope.details = response.data; //You get your data here from nodejs API, and iterate details in your View
      });*/
    
    
      $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
            var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
            $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
        }
    });
```

```css
.table-header 
{
background-color: lightskyblue;  
}
```

```html
<!-this is your HTML ->
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js
"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Export to Excel</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#tableToExport')">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
 Export to Excel
    </button>
        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#another')">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
 Export to Excel Plain JSON
    </button>
    <div id="tableToExport">
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-header">
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Process Type</th>
            <th>Cedent</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="data in details track by $index">
            <td>{{data.team}}</td>
            <td>{{data.type}}</td>
            <td>{{data.cedent}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="another">
      {{details}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154709/discussion-on-answer-by-rahul-call-nodejs-function-in-angularjs). If you need to add information to the question, edit it. Other relevant information should be added to the answer.

Comment: How to change name for exported excel sheet with current timestamp?Means Excel sheet name should come with time.

Answer (score 0):

in angular you can call api using this way

```
$http.get("/myDBfunction")
.then(function(response){ $scope.details = response.data; });
```

please see for more [this doc](https://www.sitepoint.com/api-calls-angularjs-http-service/)